# 2 MySQL instances in the same cib.xml

Tags: mysql, cluster, rhel7, pacemaker

I have a RHEL 7.3 cluster with 2 nodes, managed by Pacemaker. It's used for MySQL HA. I currently have one MySQL service added to the cluster (MySQL 5.2):

```
<primitive class="ocf" id="mysqldb1" provider="heartbeat" type="mysql">
  <instance_attributes id="mysqldb1-instance_attributes">
    <nvpair id="mysqldb1-instance_attributes-binary" name="binary" value="/usr/sbin/mysqld"/>
    <nvpair id="mysqldb1-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/etc/my1.cnf"/>
    <nvpair id="mysqldb1-instance_attributes-socket" name="socket" value="/opt/mysql1/mysql.sock"/>
    ....
  </instance_attributes>
</primitive>
```

I need to add a second instance of MySQL to the cluster (MySQL 5.7):

```
<primitive class="ocf" id="mysqldb2" provider="heartbeat" type="mysql">
  <instance_attributes id="mysqldb2-instance_attributes">
    <nvpair id="mysqldb2-instance_attributes-binary" name="binary" value="/opt/mysql2/sbin/mysqld"/>
    <nvpair id="mysqldb2-instance_attributes-config" name="config" value="/etc/my2.cnf"/>
    <nvpair id="mysqldb2-instance_attributes-socket" name="socket" value="/opt/mysql2/mysql.sock"/>
    ....
  </instance_attributes>
</primitive>
```

The problem is that only the first instance of MySQL found in cib.xml is started by the cluster. So if I put the mysqldb1 first, and second the mysqldb2 in cib.xml, only the mysqldb1 will be started. When the second instance is reached there is this error: INFO: MySQL already running. This is the log:

```
sql-02 mysql(mysqldb1)[61344]: INFO: MySQL is not running
sql-02 mysql(mysqldb1)[61344]: INFO: MySQL started
sql-02 crmd[60496]:  notice: Result of start operation for mysqldb1 on sql-02: 0 (ok) | call=46 key=mysqldb1_start_0 confirmed=true cib-update=29
sql-02 mysql(mysqldb2)[61648]: INFO: MySQL already running
sql-02 crmd[60496]:  notice: Result of start operation for mysqldb2 on sql-02: 0 (ok) | call=48 key=mysqldb2_start_0 confirmed=true cib-update=31
```

If I manually start the 2 instances they work fine. Is it possible to have these 2 instances of MySQL running at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, here is the solution I found. If you want 2 MySQL databases to run simultaneously on the same node, you have to make sure that the **socket**, **datadir**, **log** and **pid** parameters are different. I had the first 3 parameters OK, but I didn't set up a pid parameter for neither instance. After I added these lines:

```
<nvpair id="mysqldb1-instance_attributes-pid" name="pid" value="/var/run/mysql1/mysqld.pid"/>

<nvpair id="mysqldb2-instance_attributes-pid" name="pid" value="/var/run/mysql2/mysqld.pid"/>
```

both instances of MySQL are started OK by the cluster and they run simultaneously without issues.